# CKEditor v3 not wrapping text in <p> tags when pasting into the editor

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor, html-editor

Is it possible to force CKEditor HTML Editor to wrap Paragraph tags around content when pasting in text into the editor?

I am running version 3.6.1

Comment: you might want to check here:   http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's different. Usually people want to turn off forced <p> tags, not turn them on, because they are turned on by default in CKEditor. Try using this code in config.js:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```